# bootloader lock failure standard unlocking commands not working thinking its hash failure or sst key corrupted

Tags: hash, key, bootloader, missing-data, sst

I do not know why but when y friend gets inebriated she like to hook her phone up to a PC and play with it. she has a basic knowledge of ADB and fastboot commmand and i verified with her what was thrown. When she went to re-lock the bootloader it did not with thisI did. she downloaded Google minimal sdk tools to get the updated ADB and Fastboot then went all the way and got mfastboot from Motorola to insure parsing for flashing. All of these fastboot packages were also tested on Mac and Linux Ubuntu, on Windows 8.1 Pro N Update 1 and Windows 7 Professional N SP2 (all x64). Resulted in the same errors. She is super thorough and I only taught here how to manually erase and flash no scripts or tool kits.

> fastboot oem lock

and it returned.

> (bootloader) FAIL: Please run fastboot oem lock begin first!
>
> (bootloader) sst lock failure!
>
> FAILED (remote failure)
>
> finished. total time: 0.014s

Then tried again, then again, and then yep again. At this this point she either read the log and followed it. personally though I think based on the point she starts playing with phones it more likely she started to panic because she needs the bootloader locked for work and started attempting to flash.

> fastboot oem lock begin

and it returned.

> M:\SHAMU\FACTORY IMAGE\shamu-lmy47z>fastboot oem lock begin
>   ...
>
> (bootloader) Ready to flash signed images
>
> OKAY [  0.121s]
>   finished. total time: 0.123s
>
> FACTORY IMAGE\shamu-lmy47z>fastboot flash boot boot.img
>
> target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
>
> sending 'boot' (7731 KB)...
>   OKAY [  0.252s]
>   writing 'boot'...
>
> (bootloader) Preflash validation failed
>   FAILED (remote failure)
>   finished. total time: 0.271s

Then the bootloader log stated

> cmd: oem lock
>
> hab check failed for boot
>
> failed to validate boot image

upon flashing boot.img the Bootloader Logs lists "Mismatched partition size (boot)".
 intresting sometimes it returns

> fastboot oem lock begin
>   ...
>   (bootloader) Ready to flash signed images
>
> OKAY [  0.121s]
>
> finished. total time: 0.123s
>
> fastboot flash boot boot.img
>
> target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
>
> sending 'boot' (7731 KB)...
>
> OKAY [  0.252s]
>
> writing 'boot'...
>
> (bootloader) Preflash validation failed
>
> FAILED (remote failure)
>
> finished. total time: 0.271s

I logged the partitions to see if they are zeroed out indicating  bad emmc but they are not.

> ## cat /proc/partitions
>
> cat /proc/partitions
>   major minor  #blocks  name
>
> 179        0   61079552 mmcblk0
>
> 179        1     114688 mmcblk0p1
>
> 179        2      16384 mmcblk0p2
>
> 179        3        384 mmcblk0p3
>
> 179        4         56 mmcblk0p4
>
> 179        5         16 mmcblk0p5
>
> 179        6         32 mmcblk0p6
>
> 179        7       1024 mmcblk0p7
>
> 179        8        256 mmcblk0p8
>
> 179        9        512 mmcblk0p9
>
> 179       10        500 mmcblk0p10
>
> 179       11       4156 mmcblk0p11
>
> 179       12        384 mmcblk0p12
>
> 179       13       1024 mmcblk0p13
>
> 179       14        256 mmcblk0p14
>
> 179       15        512 mmcblk0p15
>
> 179       16        500 mmcblk0p16
>
> 179       17          4 mmcblk0p17
>
> 179       18        512 mmcblk0p18
>
> 179       19       1024 mmcblk0p19
>
> 179       20       1024 mmcblk0p20
>
> 179       21       1024 mmcblk0p21
>
> 179       22       1024 mmcblk0p22
>
> 179       23      16384 mmcblk0p23
>
> 179       24      16384 mmcblk0p24
>
> 179       25       2048 mmcblk0p25
>
> 179       26      32768 mmcblk0p26
>
> 179       27        256 mmcblk0p27
>
> 179       28         32 mmcblk0p28
>
> 179       29        128 mmcblk0p29
>
> 179       30       8192 mmcblk0p30
>
> 179       31       1024 mmcblk0p31
>
> 259        0       2528 mmcblk0p32
>
> 259        1          1 mmcblk0p33
>
> 259        2          8 mmcblk0p34
>
> 259        3      16400 mmcblk0p35
>
> 259        4       9088 mmcblk0p36
>
> 259        5      16384 mmcblk0p37
>
> 259        6     262144 mmcblk0p38
>
> 259        7      65536 mmcblk0p39
>
> 259        8       1024 mmcblk0p40
>
> 259        9    2097152 mmcblk0p41
>
> 259       10   58351488 mmcblk0p42
>
> 179       32       4096 mmcblk0rpmb
>
> 254        0   58351488 dm-0

Ive asked for log or the total process to see the full warning, error, and failure message but she is super far on business. From what I do have and what literature i have started to crack. I am starting to believe from  all my research and learnng about the android boot proccess. Maybe there is a missing or corrupted key in the SST table which is I beleieved called the bigtable to google. or a hash password failure when locking the bootloader security down or i could be way off please let me know. What I do not know how to investigate or disprove this issue to move on. Would I be able to get confirmation through a stack trace for missing or corrupted coding. So then it can be a puzzle thats solved. Honestly though this has become a puzzle that begs to be solved not an emergency thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try  "fastboot flashing lock" command instead.